# catalog/product_new no longer displays anything

Tags: product, ce-1.7.0.2, product-list, date, new-products

So, I've been using this as a New Arrivals part of my home page to display those products that have the most recent 'Set Product as New From Date' and 'Set Product as New To Date' parameters set up. I've been using this on our new website for over a month, and it was working fine until yesterday, when it just started not displaying any products anymore.

The code on the home page is:

```
<div>{{block type="catalog/product_new" template="webandpeople/smartcatalog/list-new.phtml" image_width="150" image_height="150" column_width="170" products_count="8"  cache_lifetime="1"}}</div>
```

Using Grayscale Full-width 2014 theme. Magento 1.7.0.2. I've already checked to make sure cache has been flushed. The ONLY thing I did recently was to add a new category that was partially hidden from certain customer groups (using the Netzarbeiter Extensions Groups Catalog 2 extension), but I even deleted that new category and reflushed cache again. Still doesn't display any new products with that code.

Comment: Did you just add the extension altogether?  Try disabling that before you get too involved.  Just to test it's not that.

Comment: I did add the extension. However, there's two caveats to that. 1 - it's been working in tandem with the theme since we launched Jan 1 (and during most of my testing last year), and 2 - I've got content that's customer group specific and sensitive on the website, which is currently being controlled by the extension. I will try that, but I'm going to have to disable a bunch of categories completely before I can try troubleshooting that.

Comment: So the extension has been working in tandem since Jan 1?  Or you just added the extension?

Comment: The extension has been working just fine since September last year, actually. When I set it up and started testing it.

Comment: OK.  I didn't see you say anything about reindexing.  Check your date ranges are valid, and reindex everything.

Comment: Just a note to remind you that the time you see on your watch may not match the time the server is set to. If your product's "New To Date" is very near the current day, there may be a time difference on the server you are not aware of and those products are actually disabled properly (even though that's not what you want).

Comment: That did it! Thank you! I hadn't even thought to reindex. Much Appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check your dates and reindex from the backend.

Comment: I'd vote positive, but don't have the 'street cred' on this site yet :)